# How to name a macro so that it can look like a constant in Elixir?

Tags: macros, naming-conventions, constants, elixir

In Erlang, we can define a macro like `-define(TIME, 60 * 60).` And from the invocation of macros such as `?TIME` we can know exactly that they are macros.

In Elixir, however, the invocation of macros look like a function call. We can't distinguish macro invocations from function calls easily.

So, is there a way that we can name some of the macros which like a constant?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Erlang, a macro works as a template. So `-define(TIME, 60 * 60)` would effectively introduce `60 * 60` into your source code (which may be pre-calculated by the compiler in this specific case).

The equivalent in Elixir would be:

```
defmacro time do
 quote do
   60 * 60
 end
end
```

But this has exactly the same issues as the Erlang one. If you actually want to compute something expensive, it will still be calculated at runtime in all places you used the macro `time`.

That said, Elixir has another construct that allows you to pre-calculate a value, at compilation time, and simply re-use in your functions, which is via attributes:

```
defmodule MyModule do
  @time 60 * 60

  def using_time do
    @time
  end
end
```

Comment: You first example doesn't work outside of a module so is not a constant that is available across the program.

Comment: It is still answered above. If you want to be available across modules, then you need to export it via a function. It is the only way.

Comment: I was just suggesting that you changed the example to  defmodule Clock do macro_defined_here end